# u_char* memcpy segfault -- tried other answers

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I have a u_char array, which changes each time I enter the loop, and a structure with a member as a u_char array. I am trying to create a vector of structures, containing all iterations of the u_char array. But I get either a segfault (when I use memcpy) or the same value duplicated (when I don't). Help? Here's the code

```
u_char * data; //contains the data I want to copy from each iteration
unsigned char mem1[bytes];
for(int i=0; i<bytes; i++) {
    mem1[i] = data[i];
}
struct load l1; //contains one member (pload of type u_char*)
l1.pload = mem1; //this gives me the same value in all elements of the vector
//I also tried using memcpy, like this:
//memcpy(&l1.pload, mem1, bytes); //this gave me a segfault 
recd.push_back(l1) //recd is a std::vector<load>
```

I print it out like so:

```
for(std::vector<load>::iterator it1 = recd.begin(); it1 != recd.end(); ++it1) {
     cout<<"\nhere\n"<<endl;
     cout<<it1->pload<<endl;
}
```

Comment: What is the definition of `struct load`?

Comment: If `l1.pload` is a `u_char*` as documented and thus no backed memory, then `memcpy (&l1.pload, ...)` will segfault as `bytes` exceeds `sizeof (u_char*)` which is 4-8 bytes, and `memcpy (l1.pload, ..)` which is what you really meant will segfault as it doesn't point anywhere.

Comment: Before using `memcpy()` you need to ensure there is enough memory allocated for `l1.pload`. Note you could use a `std::vector<unsigned char>`, as you are already use `std::vector` elsewhere, and avoid any explicit dynamic memory management.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get a segmentation fault on `memcpy` for what Steve-o and hmjd said in the comments: `li.pload` is probably just a pointer, and it's not pointing to any space of its own, so `memcpy` fails.  Depending on your compiler, it's uninitialized, or points to 0x0, and in either case, copying in to that should properly cause that error.

It's ok for `li.pload` to just be a pointer.  The trick is, `mem1` should point to new, valid data each time:

```
`u_char * mem1 = new u_char[bytes];`
```

Then your for loop (which could be replaced by `memcpy` there) will work fine, and you can keep your `l1.pload = mem1`, since you'll be storing a pointer to different memory areas each time.  As it is right now, each `li.pload` is pointing to the same memory area, which is why you're seeing the same value in each record.

Of course, since you're allocating memory, when you're done with your vector, you'll have to remember to delete `pload` for each `load` in your vector.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I didn't realize it just need a 'new'. Thank you!